# Тест с множественным выбором ответа в javascript

Tags: javascript

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Тест (Как вы меня знаете?)</title>
    <meta charset="1251">
    <style type="text/css">
        *{
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <p>Как меня зовут?<br>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="myname" value="Гоша">
            Гоша</label>
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="myname" value="Олег">
            Олег</label>
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="myname" value="Ваня">
            Ваня</label>
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="myname" value="Забыл">
            Забыл</label>
    </p>
    <label for="street">Самая длинная улица в городе?</label><br>
    <select name="street" id="select">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="Алапаевец">Алапаевец</option>
        <option value="Московская">Московская</option>
    </select>
    <p>Осадки это:<br>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="testGeorge" value="Дождь">
            Дождь</label>
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="testGeorge" value="Снег">
            Снег</label>
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="testGeorge" value="Кирпич">
            Кирпич</label>
        <br>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="button" id="calc" value="Подсчитать результаты">
        <input type="reset" value="Сброс">
    </p>
    Итого баллов: <input type="text" name="result" readonly>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    calc.onclick = function(){
        var myform = this.form,
            chbx = myform['testGeorge'],
            sum = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < chbx.length; i++){
            if(chbx[i].checked && (chbx[i].value == 'Дождь' || chbx[i].value == 'Снег'))
                sum++;
        }
        if(myform.myname.value == 'Ваня') sum++;
        if(myform.street.value == 'Московская') sum++;

        myform.result.value = sum;
    };
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста! В Вопросе про осадки, нужно выбрать несколько вариантов ответа, при выборе, 2 правильных, в строке итоги он выдает 2 ответа, а нужно чтобы 1, как исправить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]